# c# How to load data to Datagridview using a file with the extension .sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I need to load data do DatagridView executing .sql file.

I know i can use something like this :

```
var connString = @"Data Source=serwer01;Initial Catalog=PolsatCyfrowy;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select top 10 idkontraktu,DataZamowienia,idOsobyDoKontaktow,idZamowieniaProduktuUzupelniajacegoKontrakt from kontrakty", conn);


    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
    DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
    sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
```

But my script is 100x bigger than this. - Can't use stored procedures, and views- no permission. Just only way to do it is executing script from sql file.
Maybe should i just executenonquery? But dont know how to load data do datagridview while using Executenonquery.

Example using :

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\example.sql");
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
conn.Open();
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

But ExecutenonQuery returning only number of rows affected.

How can i load data do datagridview executing script from file?

Comment: `new SqlCommand(yourScriptLoadedFromFile, connection)`, and then use your original approach with `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the code. Just join the two code examples...

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\example.sql");
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

var connString = @"Data Source=serwer01;Initial Catalog=PolsatCyfrowy;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
conn.Open();
SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(script, conn);

SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
```